# Laravel - can a method on Eloquent model class ignore Trait?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, traits, eloquent-relationship

I have a User Model class that uses UserHasTeams trait, and this User class has a relationship method called projects. Now my question is, is it possible that somehow this projects method ignores the trait UserHasTeams because it appends the team_id in the where clause of my eloquent query, which I don't want. Here is the code

```
<?php

namespace App;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, Billable, UserHasTeams;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'company_id', 'role', 'status', 'trial_ends_at',
        'address_line_1', 'address_line_2', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode', 'country_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    protected $dates = ['trial_ends_at'];

    public function company() {
      return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }

    public function projects() {
      return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
    }
}
```

whenever I use `Project::all()`, it appends `team_id` which is accepted but for some instances, I don't want this projects method to use Trait, is It possible? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you should do it in your trait.

Comment: Can you show the code for UserHasTeams trait?

Comment: sounds like a global scope so you would need to figure out what the scope is and you could do something like `Project::withoutGlobalScope(...)->....` ... if it is being applied to all queries it is probably being booted with the model

Comment: @mrhn here it is https://github.com/mpociot/teamwork/blob/master/src/Traits/UserHasTeams.php

Comment: btw you are showing a `User` model with this trait but you are talking about running queries on `Project` ...